# Number of ordered triplets of 3 natural numbers whose product is given.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let T be the following set of ordered triplets:
$T = \{(a,b,c):a,b,c ∈ N\}$.
The number of elements in set T such that $abc = 2^5 × 3^7$ and HCF of a, b and c is 1 is ?

My attempt:

Let $a = 2^{x_a}×3^{y_a}$

$b = 2^{x_b}×3^{y_b}$

$c = 2^{x_c}×3^{y_c}$

Therefore, $ x_a + x_b + x_c = 5$ and $ y_a + y_b + y_c = 7$

Clearly, this will also include the solutions where the HCF of a, b and c is not 1. How to enforce the restriction on HCF of the three numbers?

Comment: Do you mean that no prime divides all $3$ or $a,b,c$?  But then at least one of them must be prime to $2$ and at least one of them (possibly overlapping the ones prime to $2$) must be prime to $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the greatest common divisor (highest common factor) of $a, b, c$ is $1$, at least one of the factors must be relatively prime to $2$ and at least one of the factors must be relatively prime to $3$.

If a factor is relatively prime to $2$, then it can be expressed in the form $2^03^t$, where $0 \leq t \leq 7$.  Similarly, if a factor is relatively prime to $3$, then it can be expressed in the form $2^u3^0$, where $0 \leq u \leq 5$.

If exactly two of the factors are relatively prime to $2$, the exponent of $2$ in the remaining factor must be $5$.  There are three ways to select the factor that has the exponent five.

If exactly one of the factors is relatively prime to $2$, the other factors must have positive integer exponents with sum $5$.  There are three ways to choose the factor which has exponent zero and four ways for an ordered pair of positive integers to sum to five.  Hence, there are $3 \cdot 4 = 12$ such cases.

In all, there are $3 + 12 = 15$ ways to distribute the factors of $2$ to the three factors $a, b, c$ so that at least one of $a, b, c$ is relatively prime to $2$.

If exactly two of the factors are relatively prime to $3$, then the exponent of $3$ in the remaining factor must be $7$.  There are three ways to select this factor.

If exactly one factor is relatively prime to $3$, then the other factors must have positive integer exponents of $3$ which sum to $7$.  There are three ways to select the factor that is relatively prime to $3$ and six ways for an ordered pair of positive integers to sum to $7$.  Hence, there are $3 \cdot 6 = 18$ such cases.

In all, there are $3 + 18 = 21$ ways to distribute factors of $3$ to the factors $a, b, c$ such that at least one of the factors is relatively prime to $2$.

Since the factors of $2$ and factors of $3$ can be distributed independently, there are $15 \cdot 21 = 315$ ordered triplets $(a, b, c)$ such that $abc = 2^53^7$ and $\gcd(a, b, c) = 1$.